# How calculate the conditional probabilities for Bayesian hypothesis test?

Tags: t-test, bayes-factors

Suppose that I obtain a sample $S=(S_1,\dots,S_n)$ from my research. The null hypothesis $H_0$ says that all $S_i$ are drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. The alternative hypothesis $H_1$ says that $S$ is a sample from a normal distribution with mean 3 and standard deviation 1.

Now the Bayes factor is defined by
$$\frac{P(S|H_0)}{P(S|H_1)}.$$
How do I calculate $P(S|H_0)$ and $P(S|H_1)$? If there are multiple ways, which is best in which situation?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm having difficulty reconciling your title with the body of your question. Are you asking about t testing or Bayesian hypothesis testing?

Comment: Thank you! I was mistaken in the title; the question is about Bayesian hypothesis testing

Comment: In this case (and adding an independence assumption), $P(S|H_0)$ is just $\prod_{i=1}^n P(S_i|H_0)$, each $P(S_i|H_0)$ being a normal *probability density function* evaluation. Same for $P(S_i|H_1)$ (except with different parameters used for the normal).

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed quite simple